# AWS EC2: How-to recover data from a failed linux instance having a logic volume comprising of multiple storage volumes?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, lvm

My question is related to AWS EC2 platform wherein I have a Linux instance with one root volume and data lvm volume (unencrypted and created using lvcreate & of file system XFS) comprised of 4 volumes.

Now, I have created snapshots for individual volumes but I was wondering if and how it would be possible to see its data in a separate newly built linux instance? Do I must create linux instance from the root volume instance and attach the data volumes?

Comment: Snapshots may not be consistent - data may be being written when it's run, and they might not snapshot at the same time. I strongly suggest taking an appropriate, consistent application or operating system level backup, rather than relying on snapshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to restore each snapshot to a new EBS volume, and then attach the root and data instances to a new EC2 instance. The instance will boot with the root volume from the snapshot, and should be able to reassemble the disks into your working volume.

Comment: So, essentially the data volumes are pretty much useless without latest root volume snapshot?

Comment: Oh, no, not necessarily, you may be able to only restore the Data snapshots, and attach those volumes to a new instance. However you'll likely need to run some lvm commands in order to reconstruct the array.